# How can tell if a player has performed some action in UDK?

Tags: udk, kismet

For simplicity, let's say that I want bots to kill me when I enter a room without greeting them. So in this case I would need to store, somewhere, the variable `didGreet`, which should be changed when I send the message "Hello." Then, when any pawn sees me, he will check the `didGreet` variable and if this was false he would start firing at me.

I've heard that this should be done using the `GameInfo` class, but unfortunately I don't know how to create, access and change variables there. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Is your game only going to be single-player, or are you planning to have multiple players? Since the attribute you are wanting to record is 'per player' (eg; one player greeting the bots does not mean *all* players have greeted the bots) - then this kind of variable should be stored in your `playercontroller` class. In a singleplayer game, it is quite acceptable to store such variables in your `gameinfo` class instead.

If you need to know how to do this, I recommend going through some unrealscript tutorials, there are quite a few out there! Good luck.